How to connect Hardhat with Nuxt.js (or Vue.js) and Wagmi for a blockchain project?
I am working on a blockchain project and I am using the following technologies:

Hardhat for smart contract development.

Nuxt.js (or Vue.js) for the frontend.

Wagmi for handling Web3 connections.


I am having trouble understanding how to properly connect Hardhat with my Nuxt.js or Vue.js frontend, specifically when integrating Wagmi. Could someone guide me through the steps or provide a basic setup example of how to:

Deploy contracts using Hardhat.

Connect the deployed contracts to my frontend.

Use Wagmi to interact with these contracts on the frontend.


Any example code or guidance on integrating these tools would be greatly appreciated!
I am working on a blockchain project where I have deployed a contract using Hardhat. I also set up Nuxt.js as the frontend framework and installed Wagmi to handle Web3 connections.
What I expected:

I expected to be able to connect my Nuxt.js frontend with the deployed contract using Hardhat and interact with it via Wagmi.

